# How to capture current running screenshot while app is running in background in android

Tags: android, cordova

Hello everyone I want to create a application for capturing screenshot, in my application I want to create a application which is running in background which is works as service, in this I want to capture the screen of current running apps

Presently I am using this code

```
View content = findViewById(R.id.mapview);
Bitmap bitmap = content.getDrawingCache();
FileOutputStream ostream = new FileOutputStream(file);
bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, ostream);
ostream.close();
```

This is working but it is capturing my background running app screns not current running screen